# How to fix issue HTML1402 with jquery url in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, console

I really don't understand why IE (only, ok for any other browser) gives me **HTML1402: Character reference is missing an ending semi-colon “;”** with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
        <head>
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <span id="here"></span>
                <div id="url_iframe">https://www.google.com.br/search?q=ie+html+1402+with+jquery&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gws_rd=cr</div>

        <script>
                var url_iframe = jQuery('#url_iframe').text();
                jQuery('#here').append('<iframe src="'+encodeURIComponent(url_iframe)+'" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="320" height="300"></iframe>');
        </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Some one know how to fix it, so that stop to appear in console?

I tried without encodeURIComponent and same error.

The URL is just a sample, I konw that won't work, it's a test for an issue of a very big and complex code, all I discover was if I change it to iframe instead of using jquery, no warning shows, but I need to do it with jquery, because of the data before my append in the real web application.

Comment: you could try escaping(\) the double quotes in your js string for the iframe. '<iframe src=\"'+url_iframe+'\" ><\/iframe>'..... but your experiment is bound to fail as google does not allow their content to be displayed in iframes (in any compliant web browser)

Comment: That's why I wrote "The URL is just a sample, I konw that won't work" and If you see in the code, it is already with double quotes, that's why I used single quotes in jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the error had to be a MS bug, I discovered that I was right and all I needed was to swap the div for input:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
        <head>
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <span id="here"></span>
                <input type="hidden" id="url_iframe" value="https://www.google.com.br/search?q=ie+html+1402+with+jquery&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gws_rd=cr"/>

        <script>
                var url_iframe = jQuery('#url_iframe').val();
                jQuery('#here').append('<iframe src="'+url_iframe+'" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="320" height="300"></iframe>');
        </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

If someone know how to do it with div, I will be glad if share here...

Answer (score 1):

Edge seems to see ampersands - & - within javascript as character reference eg • missing their semicolons at the end.

In the above case, use & in the URL for any "&" in Edge.
Edge is a terrible browser BTW.